# Chrome shifting divs downwards?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm having some CSS issues that seem to only occur in chrome. The site in question is liveinthelead.com, and it's still being worked on so if you notice any other strange problems feel free to let me know, I won't be offended. My main problem is this though:

In all of the browsers I've tested except for chrome the site looks fine. However, in chrome, on the main page, the middle post in the three-post divs are shifted down about 20px. But when I open up the developer interface, they shift back to where they're supposed to be! Maybe it's just a local problem, but here are some pictures of what I'm talking about. If you don't experience the same issue then maybe it's just something weird going on with my computer. Cheers.

[When I initially load the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ktvr.png)

[After I open the developer console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPg7q.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that I noticed is that in your `div#three-post` you set `float:left` to `div.member1` but not to the remaining `div.member2` or `div.member3`.

That's where I would start investigating the problem. Maybe you should set the remaining two divs to also float left. You may need to clear them afterwards too.

For the sake of convention — and so that you don't encounter this confusions again — use IDs for selecting specific elements, e.g., member1, member2, member3, and use classes for selecting multiple elements that should share the same attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to replicate on Chrome 15.

=\ could be a good thing! Try another computer!

Comment: Thanks :) I guess that's all I needed to know. Not really sure which answer I'd prefer, to be honest. Haha.